# how to get row total in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

[image]

I am trying to get Row total and column total from my dataframe. I have no issue with the column total. However, My row total is adding up all the job descriptions rather than showing total

here's my code:

```
Newdata= data.groupby(['Job Description','AgeBand'])['AgeBand'].count().reset_index(name="count")
Newdata= Newdata.sort_values(by = ['AgeBand'],ascending=True)
df=Newdata.pivot_table(index='Job Description', values = 'count', columns = 'AgeBand').reset_index()


df.loc['Total',:]= df.sum(axis=0)
df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df=df.fillna(0).astype(int, errors='ignore')
df
```

Comment: Structuring your question will also help to make clear what you try to accomplish. Now you start with the desired end result with a picture, which is not clearly referred to in the text. Also the first part of the code does not add anything to solving your problem, so would leave it out. The picture also does not show the wrong output you're getting. A good question format here would be: problem statement -> input -> code+current wrong output -> desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First preselect the columns you wish to add row wise, then use df.sum(axis=1).

I think you're after:

```
df.loc[:,'Total'] = df.loc[:,'20-29':'UP TO 20'].sum(axis=1)
```